# Need to draw line graphs

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to EXCEL VBA.
Please provide me help for following requirement.

**Requirement**: Need an EXCEL VBA macro for following requirement.

There are `n` number of columns. 1st column is text. all other columns are numbers. I need to draw line graphs for

1. 1st column(X axis) and 2nd column (Y axis)
2. 1st column(X axis) and 3rd column (Y axis)
3. .
4. .
5. .
   n. 1st column(X axis) and nth column (Y axis)

So the state is 1st column is constant for all the time. How to loop the above state by changing column dynamically?.

Let me know if I've not explained clearly.

Comment: Did you try recording a macro?

Comment: Yes , but I don't know how to change the column range in run time. Can you give me some example if possible .

Comment: First create a macro which creates a chart for Col 1 and Col 2. Paste the code that you get in your question and then we will take it form there :)

Comment: Is following code enough.
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:A10,B1:B10").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "'Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$10,'Sheet1'!$B$1:$B$10")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    Range("A1:A10,C1:C10").Select
    Range("C1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "'Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$10,'Sheet1'!$C$1:$C$10")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
End Sub

Comment: Can you please edit your question and paste the code there. The code is hardly readable in comments :)

Comment: See if you can join me here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17103/need-to-draw-line-graphs

Answer (score 0):

basically this is a general version of your recorded macro, it will loop all columns, all rows.

```
Sub PlotLineGraph()
    Dim height As Long
    Dim width As Long
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet
    Dim targetWs As Worksheet
    Dim targetWorksheetName As String
    Dim targetRange As Range

    Dim targetChart As Chart
    Dim chartsPerRow As Long
    Dim chartWidth As Double
    Dim chartHeight As Double

    'customize the parameters
    chartsPerRow = 2
    chartWidth = 300
    chartHeight = 300
    Set sourceWs = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' replace Sheet1 with the sheet name the data is stored ( Case sensitive)
    targetWorksheetName = "Sheet2"   ' the output sheet name
    Set targetWs = Worksheets(targetWorksheetName)

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'optional
    'this part deletes all previous shapes on the target worksheet
    For Each Shape In targetWs.Shapes
        Shape.Delete
    Next Shape
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    With sourceWs
        height = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' getting height of column A
        width = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'getting columns of row 1
        If width > 1 Then
            For j = 2 To width
                targetWs.Activate
                targetWs.Shapes.AddChart.Select
                ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
                Set targetChart = ActiveChart
                .Activate
                Set targetRange = Union(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(height, 1)), .Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(height, j)))
                targetChart.SetSourceData Source:=targetRange
                With targetChart.Parent
                    .height = chartHeight
                    .width = chartWidth
                    .Top = CLng((j - 2) / chartsPerRow) * chartHeight
                    .Left = ((j - 2) Mod chartsPerRow) * chartWidth
                End With
            Next j
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually I tried to avoid using Select, but I have no idea how to.
If I do a "Dim newChart as Chart"

then "set newChart = .Shapes.AddChart" , it will give a typemismatch error message to me...

Comment: Thanks a lot Friend :) this is what exactly I want :)

Comment: @Siddharth Can we put the graphs in sequence order in sheet2 like each row can have 3 graphs? Eg: (1graphs 2ndGraph 3rdGraph) (4th..) (n-2th n-1th nth)  basically i want to avoid overlapping the graphs when i create for multiple columns.

Comment: @Karthik207 how's the progress?